# Easiest way to "browse" to a page and submit form in Java

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, httprequest, headless-browser

What I need to do is browse to a webpage, login, then browse to another webpage on that site that requires you to be logged in, so it needs to save cookies. After that, I need to click an element on that page, in which I would fill out the form and get the message that the webpage returns to me. The reason I need to actually go to the page and click the button as suppose to just navigating directly to the link is because the you are assigned a session ID every time you log in and click the link, and its always different. The button looks like this, its not a normal href link:

```
<span id=":tv" idlink="" class="sA" tabindex="0" role="link">Next</span>
```

Anyway, what would be the easiest way to do this? Thanks.

Update:
After trying HTMLunit, and other headless browser libraries, it doesnt seem that its happening using anything "headless." Another thing that I recently found out about this page is that that all the HTML is in some weird format... Its all  inside a script tag. Here is a sample.

```
"?ui\x3d2\x26view\x3dss\x26mset\x3dmain\x26ver\x3d-68igm85d1771\x26am\x3d!Zsl-0RZ-XLv0BO3aNKsL0sgMg3nH10t5WrPgJSU8CYS-KNWlyrLmiW3HvC5ykER_n_5dDw\x26fri"],"http://example.com/?ctx\x3d%67mail\x26hl\x3den",,0,"Gmail","Gmail",[["us","c130f0854ca2c2bb",[["n"],["m","New features!"],["u"],["k","0"],["p","1000:500000,10,200000,5,100000,3,75000,2,0,1"],["h","https://survey.googleratings.com/wix/p1679258.aspx?l\x3d1033"],["at","query,5,contacts,5,adv,5,cf,5,default,20"],["v","https://www.youtube.com/embed/Ra8HG6MkOXY?showinfo\x3d0"],
```

When I do inspect element on the button, the HTML code that I posted above for the button comes up, but not when doing view source. Basically, what I am going to need to do is use some sort of GUI and have the user navigate to the link and then have the program fill out the info. Does anyone know how I can do this? Thanks.

Comment: Check out Selenium and Selenium IDE. There are numerous articles and how-tos to be found online that will get you up and working in a few hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible in Selenium as others have noted.

I have used Selenium to login then crawl a site and discover every permuation of values for every form on the site (30+ forms). These values are later used to fill and submit the form with a specific perumation of values. This site was very JS/jQuery heavy and I used Selenium's built-in support of javascript executor, css selectors, and XPath to accomplish this.

I implemented HtmlUnit and HttpUnit as faster alternatives, but found they were not as reliable as Selenium given the JS semantics of the site I was crawling.

It's hard to give you code on how to accomplish it because your Selenium implementation will be quite page-specific and I can't look at the page you're coding against to figure out what's going on with that button script junk. However, I have include some possibly relevant selenium code (Java) snippets:

```
Element element = driver.findElements(By.id(value)); //find element on page
List<Element> buttons = parent.findElements(By.xpath("./tr/td/button")); //find child element
button.click();
element.submit() //submit enclosing form
element.sendKeys(text); //enter text in an input
String elementText = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].innerText || arguments[0].textContent", element); //interact with a selenium element via JS
```

If you are coding similar functions on different pages, then [PageObjects](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects) behind interfaces can help.

The link Anew posted is a good starting point and good ol' StackOverflow has answers to just about any Selenium problem ever.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the 5 Minute Getting Started Guide for Selenium: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted

Comment: Another invaluable tool in that stack is the SeleniumIDE plug in for firefox. It allows you to record your actions on a page, and then export the interaction to Java code.

Answer (score 2):

On the login page, look at the form's HTML to see the url it posts to and the url parameters. Then request that url with the same parameters filled in with correct info, and make sure to save all the cookie headers to send to the second page. Then use an html parser to find your link. There are several html parsers available on sourceforge, and you could even try java's built in xml parsers, though if the site has even a tiny html mistake they will glitch.

EDIT didn't notice the fact that it is not a normal link. In that case you will need to look at the site's javascript to see where the link leads. If the link requires javascript to run, it gets more complicated. Java is not able to execute browser javascript, but I found a library called DJ native swing which includes a web browser class that you can add to jframes. It uses your native browser to render, and to run javascript.

Comment: Would it be possible for me to have the user manually browse to the page using the GUI browser library, than have the library fill it the forms for the user from the code? This is using the DJ Native.

Comment: Yes sure. That's a good solution. Look at the DJ Native swing library. Adding a web browser to your frame is as easy as `JWebBrowser b=new JWebBrowser(); frame.add(b);`

Comment: Please see the edit of the post. Is there a way I can incorporate a GUI library like this, but than programatically fill out the form on the page? I would have the user navigate to the page and then the program would fill out forms/click buttons etc.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to browse around programmatically, try executing the login request and save the cookies then set those in the next request to the form post.

Answer (score 0):

HTMLUnit is pretty bad at processing JavaScript, the Rhino JS library produces often errors (actually no errors is much the exception). I would advise to use [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/), which is basically a framework to control headless browsers (chrome, firefox based).

For your question, the following code would do the work

```
selenium.open(myurl);
selenium.click("id=:tv");
```

You then have to wait for the page to load

```
selenium.waitForPageToLoad(someTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend htmlunit any day. It's a great library.

First, check out their web page(http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) to get htmlunit up and running. Make sure you use the latest snapshot(2.12 when writing this)

Try these settings to ignore pretty much any obstacle:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_17);
webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
```

Then when fetching your page, make sure you wait for background Javascript before doing anything with the page, like posting a login form:

```
//Get Page
HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("https://login-url/");

//Wait for background Javascript
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);

//Get first form on page
HtmlForm form = page1.getForms().get(0);

//Get login input fields using input field name
HtmlTextInput userName = form.getInputByName("UserName");
HtmlPasswordInput password = form.getInputByName("Password");

//Set input values
userName.setValueAttribute("MyUserName"); 
password.setValueAttribute("MyPassword"); 

//Find the first button in form using name, id or xpath
HtmlElement button = (HtmlElement) form.getFirstByXPath("//button");

//Post by clicking the button and cast the result, login arrival url, to a new page and repeat what you did with page1 or something else :) 
HtmlPage page2 = (HtmlPage) button.click(); 

//Profit
System.out.println(page2.asXml());
```

I hope this basic example will help you!