# Scraping data from webpage using Java?

Tags: java, twitter, web-scraping, bots, headless-browser

I'm creating a twitter bot for one of my classes to practice using queues and to build my resume.

I want the bot to scrape twitter handles from a paper.li newsletter and then send the user  tweet.

here's an example webpage. 
http://paper.li/profkane/1335985326

My reasoning, originally was to grab the link of the webpage, and then get the page source, browse it for @twitterhandle and then add those to a queue to be used later when constructing the messages.

I looked up the page source but I cannot find twitter names anywhere on the webpage. Is this still possible to do in Java?

Comment: Are you mixing Java with Javascript?

Comment: I don't plan to unless i have to. I was hoping i could do all of this in java. I'm not proficient in javascript

Comment: can u describe a bit better what is your intention? I don't get "twitter handle" part somehow. .Only thing I get about twitter on example link u gave is widget which is updating itself with tweets using javascript

Comment: yes, paper.li uses javascript to display tweets. My bot would scrap paper.li for the tweeter user name's "@name" and then send them a tweet back. in this particular case, i want to tweet them back how many times they were listed on the front page of the paper.li website i listed above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a library that has javascript support. I use **HtmlUnit** for this which is a great library for replicating browser behavior!

See my modified answer [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740801/easiest-way-to-browse-to-a-page-and-submit-form-in-java/14905070#14905070) below for a simple example of how to access a page with javascript.

**First**, check out their web page(http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) to get htmlunit up and running. Make sure you use the latest snapshot(2.12 when writing this)

Try these settings to ignore pretty much any obstacle:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_17);
webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
```

Then when fetching your page, make sure you wait for background Javascript before doing anything with the page, like waiting for background javascript.

```
//Get Page
HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("https://login-url/");

//Wait for background Javascript
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);

//Get full page _after_ javascript has rendered it fully
System.out.println(page1.asXml());
```

I hope this basic example will help you!

You can use HtmlUnit to do pretty much anything a browser can do, but programmatically.

Comment: thanks this is interesting stuff. I just realized there's another layer of complexity. The page that i linked to above does not include the twitter handle name. I have to individually click on each link and then a small box is displayed using javascript that includes the twitter handle (@name). will htmlPage handle this. I guess i have to print the entire page everytime i click on a link.

Comment: actually i just checked the sample webpage and the links display the twitter name, not the twitter handle (@name), which links to www.twitter.com/@name in the xml file i get from htmlUnit will it include <a href="www.twitter.com/@name">Twitter Name</a>

Comment: You can do that with htmlunit. If the links are hidden divs with already loaded data it should be visible in the source code, no need to get htmlunit to click them. If you'd like to interact with the page, see my original answer in the linked question in the beginning of my answer!

Comment: You can mark this as answer if it helped you even if you have low rep, but it seems to me you have 19 rep :)

Comment: can you link me to where i  can download 2.12 version? i have 2.11 and it is not working. Best

Comment: You can find on their build server, here: http://build.canoo.com/htmlunit/artifacts/ Try your code on this simple page first: http://simile.mit.edu/crowbar/test.html if javascript execution works, content will say "Hi Crowbar". If javascript does not work, it says "Hello lame ..."

Comment: thank's I used 2.11 and it worked but wasn't as fast. btw there's a bug in your answer.//Get full page _after_ javascript has rendered it fully should be System.out.println(page1.asXml());

Comment: Whoops, sorry. Copied my code from an old answer where there is two pages. I'll update my example. Glad it worked!

Answer (score 0):

As far as scraping is concerned, you can scrape the whole page and look for the twitter id(or handle). When I checked the sample page I could not find the handle as such, but in the Twitter icon has the link to user's account. You can use this to get the handle.  If you are looking for scraping libraries in Java you can give JSOUP a shot.